# Use timestamp from Mysql in humanize.Time() package

Tags: go, timestamp, mariadb

I have a mariaDB database with a timestamp field. I want the values from that field being parsed to `time.Time()` values. This is possible by adding the `?parseTime=true` to the connection string. After fetching a row, I want to use the value (which is time.Time) with [humanize.Time()](https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize). Unfortunately values within the past 60 minutes are converted by humanize.Time() as `1 hour from now`. When I put directly a time.Time() value into humanize.Time(), it gives me `x seconds ago`.

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I think I need to convert `2017-04-23 14:00:16 +0000 UTC` to `2017-04-23 14:00:16.370758048 +0200 CEST`, but how?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    humanize "github.com/dustin/go-humanize"
)

// value from database: 2017-04-23 14:00:16 +0000 UTC
// typical time.Now() value: 2017-04-23 14:00:16.370758048 +0200 CEST

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
    beforeParsing := "2017-04-23 14:00:16 +0000 UTC"

    t, err := time.Parse(layout, beforeParsing)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(humanize.Time(t))
}
```

Comment: "Unfortunately values within the past 60 minutes are converted by humanize.Time() as 1 hour from now" --- that does not sound right: https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize/blob/master/times_test.go What do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem with the database at all, but with humanize.Time. Am I misunderstanding something?  What happens if you limit your test code to using a manually-input time, instead of reading from the db? Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: The humanize package works fine; when I use time.Time() in the humanize.Time() function, I receive values like "4 seconds ago". So that's great. My problem is that I cannot convert the database value `2017-04-23 14:00:16 +0000 UTC` to `2017-04-23 14:00:16 +0000 UTC`. So I think I need to convert UTC to CEST.

Comment: I suggest focusing your question on "I cannot convert the database value `2017-04-23 14:00:16 +0000 UTC` to 2`017-04-23 14:00:16 +0000 UTC`" and removing the details about humanize.Time

Comment: You don't need to convert it manually, `time.Parse` will do the job. You can verify the result by adding `fmt.Printf("Time Difference = %v\n", time.Now().Sub(t))` to your example.

Comment: IMHO, nothing is wrong with the example code. I guess, the time is stored in the database as `Local` timestamp, but when you read it through go code, it's interpreted as UTC timestamp. If yes, according to [this](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support), you may need to specify the timezone explicitly by adding `loc=CEST` to the connection string.